# Spark - Avro Reads Schema but DataFrame Empty

Tags: scala, apache-spark, avro, spark-avro, gobblin

I am using [Gobblin](http://gobblin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to periodically extract relational data from `Oracle`, convert it to `avro` and publish it to `HDFS`

My dfs directory structure looks like this

```
-tables
  |
  -t1
   |
   -2016080712345
    |
    -f1.avro
   |
   -2016070714345
    |
    -f2.avro
```

I am trying to read from it like so:

```
val sq = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
  .load("/user/username/gobblin/job-output/tables/t1/")
```

When I run `printSchema` I can see that the schema is interpreted correctly.

However, when I run `count` or `show`, the `DataFrames` are empty. I have verified that the `.avro` files are not empty by converting it to `JSON`

```
java -jar avro-tools-1.7.7.jar  tojson --pretty t1/20160706230001_append/part.f1.avro > t1.json
```

I suspect that it may have something to do with the directory structure. Perhaps the Spark avro libraries only look one level down from the root for `.avro` files. The logs seem to indicate that only the directories under t1 were listed on the driver:

> 16/07/07 10:47:09 INFO avro.AvroRelation: Listing hdfs://myhost.mydomain.com:8020/user/username/gobblin/job-output/tables/t1 on driver
>
> 16/07/07 10:47:09 INFO avro.AvroRelation: Listing hdfs://myhost.mydomain.com:8020/user/username/gobblin/job-output/tables/t1/20160706230001_append on driver

Has anyone experienced something similar, or know how to get around this? I'd hat to have to point lower than the `t1` directory because the names are generated by a timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same problem. While I don't know the exact reason for the problem, there is a way to go around this:

Instead of pointing to the parent directory, use wildcard and point to avro file level.

```
sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro")\
    .load("/path/to/tables/t1/*/*.avro")
```